# Просмотр XDC-файлов

Tags: c++, xml, doc

Написал код на С++. И при помощи авто-документации получил файлы `.xdc`. Что мне с ними делать? Читать их так как они есть невозможно. Я так полагаю их надо конвертировать в `HTML` или `MD`. Какую утилиту посоветуете?

Comment: а что за авто-документацию вы используете то? Обычно используют doxygen для этих целей, а он генерит документацию в html и latex

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я использую стандартную в Visual Studio. А doxygen синтаксис не очень. Мне больше xml-синтаксис нравится

Comment: в таком случае вы сами же себя загоняете в проблему: ваш формат документации понятен только для vs, в то время как doxygen не зависит от ide - это отдельный инструмент. При этом doxygen не только для с/с++, но еще и для кучи других языков. Я уж не говорю о том, что она, по сути, является стандартом в области документации кода на с/c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь они полезны за счет отображения описания непосредственно в подсказках intellisense. А если нужна отдельная справка, то их можно скармливать в DocFX, Sandcastle или в тот же doxygen и генерировать html / chm / pdf и т.п.